# How to keep timer running when i go to the other frame Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to actionscript.
I want to know how to run timer class and keep running even when i go to other frame.
For example. I run timer in frame 2 and when i go to frame 1 timer keeps running, until i go back to frame 2 to stop the timer.
I appreciate the help.

UPDATE :
I try to make a stopwatch with these code :

```
var sec,min,hr:uint = 0;
sec_txt.text = min_txt.text = hr_txt.text = "00";
var timerStopWatch:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timerStopWatch.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent){
    var sec:String = String(uint(timerStopWatch.currentCount%60));
    var min:String = String(uint((timerStopWatch.currentCount/60)%60));
    var hr:String = String(uint((timerStopWatch.currentCount/60)/60));

    sec_txt.text = (uint(sec)< 10) ? "0" + sec:sec;
    min_txt.text = (uint(min)< 10) ? "0" + min:min;
    hr_txt.text = (uint(hr) < 10) ? "0" + hr:hr;
}
```

When i start the timer it work, but when i go to the second frame or another it stop and show a output error :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

    at Stopwatch_fla::MainTimeline/timerHandler()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

What i want is, when i start the Timer and go to the other frame it will still running(ticking) and when i go back to the Timer frame i could stop it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Yes i have. This is my firat question and i try my best to ask question that senseable.

Comment: **First**. Not clear what do you mean by "*timer*". An instance of **Timer** class? A countdown timer displayed as **TextField** with text like 00:01:59? Something else? **Second**. As Maciej mentioned, StackOverflow is not a free code delivery service. Normally you need to show the code you tried so far and explain the **specific technical** problem you're having with it (e.g. *runtime error* or *not working as expected*). **Third**. The fact you are new to ActionScript (the programming, the world) does not give you any discounts or privileges, it's a good idea not to mention it at all.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes the timer that i mention is a timer class.
var timerStopWatch:Timer = new Timer(1000);

Comment: @Ayasatomi Thank you for understanding. The question looks much more appropriate now. Next, learn of the nature of #1009 error: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/actionscript-3/2098/understanding-the-error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-obje#t=20170902172604070097 When you're done, go to **File** -> **Publish Settings** menu and check **Permit Debugging** option on. This will give you the exact line that produces the error.

Comment: okey, i understand. Thank you for the help @Organis.

Comment: First, use the debugger to find out which exact line of code is throwing the error.    Most likely, one or more of your text fields don't exist on other frames when the timer ticks.  `sec/min/hr_txt`.   That or you destroy your timer reference but don't remove the event listener.    Show how you `stop` your timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  if you're going to be re-visiting the frame where your posted code lives, you want to make sure that timer doesn't get re-created every time and cause a memory leak.

Change the following line

```
var timerStopWatch:Timer = new Timer(1000);
```

To these two lines:

```
var timerStopWatch:Timer;
if(!timerStopWatch) timerStopWatch = new Timer(1000);
```

This will ensure your timer is only created once.  That event listener will keep the timer in memory, so if you're constantly creating new timers and adding a listener to them, they will all stay in memory and your application will get slower and slower.

Second, make sure you clean up after yourself.

When you want your timer to be gone, stop it, remove the event listener and null the reference:

```
timerStopWatch.stop();
timerStopWatch.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timerStopWatch = null;
```

Third, if your going to have this object span multiple frames, anything that is referenced in the event handler needs to persist in those frames as well.

That means:

```
sec_txt
min_txt
hr_txt
```

All have to exist on any frame where this timer is running.  Make sure on those frames that they have their instance names set properly.

OR, check if they exist prior to using them:

```
if(sec_txt) sec_txt.text = (uint(sec)< 10) ? "0" + sec:sec;
```

Comment: Thank @BadFeelingAboutThis for the explanation, it work for me. Appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem you are probably typing code in the frame itsel. Write a document class and create your timer in there, so no matter which frame, all properties are still there and keep running.

Comment: Thank you. I give it a try.

Comment: Or, in simple case, make another layer and create the timer there. Make sure the new layer has frames for both frame1 and frame2, but that frame2 isn't a keyframe.

Comment: Actually, timeline code is not scoped to individual frames, but to the timeline itself.   For example, if on frame 3 you had: `var foo = "foofoo"`,  once you visit frame 3,  that var (foo) will then be available on all frames of the timeline.   Code on the first frame of the main timeline will be scoped the exact same as public vars/methods in a document class.